# How do I restore mana?

Tags: heroes-of-might-and-magic-3

I've seen wells that fully replenish the mana of a hero that visits, but since that is just a map feature, I can't always rely on it to be there. How else can I restore the mana of my caster heroes?

Comment: Ref: http://heroes.thelazy.net/wiki/Magic_Well

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can also restore mana by spending 1 turn in a castle/town that you own that has a mage guild built in it. It will restore the entire mana bar.

There are items:

```
 Charm of Mana - Hero recovers 1 extra spell point per day
 Talisman of Mana - Hero recovers 2 extra spell points per day
 Mystic Orb of Mana - Hero recovers 3 extra spell points per day
```

A secondary skill (Mysticism) also boosts daily mana regeneration rate.

Comment: @Sorean, Do you mean that a level 1 mage guild is sufficient?

Comment: If you end the day in the town, yes.

Answer (score 3):

Dungeon town has the "Mana vortex" building, it allows to instantly set your hero's spell points to 2*maximum (once in a week). If you are going to visit the town anyway, then it's basically free (no need to end turn in a town).

Answer (score 1):

The adventure map structure [**Magic Spring**](http://web.archive.org/web/20030215144356/http://www.astralwizard.com:80/heroes3/h3grden5.htm) (found on rough terrain, the Stronghold's native ground) acts in the same way as the Mana Vortex building in a Dungeon town: it sets the hero's spell points to twice the maximum amount. A Magic Spring has two entrance points; each can be used once a week.